# How can i control Perfino agent logging behaviour

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, perfino

Is there any way of controlling or disabling the logging of perfino agent? Perfino agent stores log file inside docker container which it is run on, under `/opt/namename/.perfino/log/<name_provided_in_VM_parameter>.log` which is a problem in my use case. Container runs tomcat which stores application. Log doesn't seem to store anything useful or important as after I deleted it I've seen no issues inside perfino UI. I haven't seen anything about logging of agent in [perfino documentation](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/perfino/help/doc/main/monitoring.html).
The strangest thing about this issue is I noticed it on one application (Let's call it APP_1) , but on another one (Let's call it APP_2), using similar image with tomcat, it does not occur. Strangely changing JDK and tomcat version in APP_2 leads to generating troublesome log. I've tried using JDK 8 and tomcat 8.5 in APP_1 (since this configuration is used in APP_2 and it does not genereate log), but it does not change a thing.
I've found a config file under `/opt/namename/.perfino/config/g=<nameOfApplication>.cfg`, but I've noticed no information about logging (It's not very readable, I assume it is not to be changed manually).

So after this a bit long introduction, my question is: Is there any way of controlling the logging of perfino agent? Maybe through logback or tomcat config since I see no way of configuration using perfino UI or setup.

Part of log file:

```
inst> com.perfino.agent.e.a.e.<init>(ejt:170)
inst> com.perfino.agent.e.a.e.<init>(ejt:153)
inst> com.perfino.agent.e.a.a(ejt:223)
inst> com.perfino.agent.e.i.transform(ejt:83)
inst> java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
inst> java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
inst> java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563)
inst> java.management/sun.management.Util.newObjectName(Util.java:52)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable logging by appending `,logEnabled=false` to the `-javaagent` VM parameter.

A different log file can be specified by appending `,logFile=<path to log file>`.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. `,logFile=<path to log file>` works just fine, but when i replace it with `,logEnabled=false` I see no effect. Are You sure it's correct? And where have You found this information, It might be usefuk in case of future issues.

Comment: What perfino version do you use? `logEnabled` is available since perfino 3.2. Indeed these options are not documented, I will add them to the documentation.

Comment: It seems that was the case. Containers are provided with perfino agent jar, and it seems it was outdated. I'll run some tests and accept the answer. Thank You very much. And if You have the power, please make sure this information makes it's way to the documentation of perfino. It's a shame this feature wasn't even mentioned. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, these properties will be documented in 4.0.1.

Comment: One more thing, I noticed that after I changed the jar provided to agent, log is not generated when `logEnabled=false` (which is nice), but changing it to true have no effect, meaning there is still no log. It still fixes my issue, as I want to get rid of the log, but it doesn't seem like a proper behaviour. The `logFile`property seems to be working, meaning it creates the directory for the log, but it stays empty as there is no log to put there. Please consider editing Your answer by adding information, that version of agent might be a key to the problem for future people having similar issue